# Why do the electrons from the 20 V battery not flow into that of the 4V battery in the given circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

In this circuit, no electrons will flow between B and C. But I think otherwise. I think that electrons from the negative terminal of the $20V$ battery must also go into the positive terminal of the $4V$ battery, through C and towards B. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

BC is not part of any circuit. It just creates a voltage offset between the two circuits. There will only be a transient current upon connecting the 4V source.

Comment: What does 'transient' current mean, exactly? And 'voltage offset'. I am a beginner at electric current. So hope you don't mind answering these questions.

Comment: It means a temporary current until a new charge equilibrium is established. This happens because of capacitance and induction not included in ideal circuits.

Comment: What effect does 'voltage offset' have? Also, can you explain why my reasoning, as mentioned in my question, is not correct?

Comment: You are right that some electrons will go to the +4V terminal but that is a transient effect. There will be no dc current.

Comment: A voltage effect has no effect in circuit theory. As long as your 4V source does not drive a closed circuit no current flows. In practice, a large voltage offset will cause sparks and is dangerous.